# Ubuntu Configuration for Google code labs Errors

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

> ```
> joseph@joseph-APSO:/$ npm install
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
> npm WARN !invalid#1 No description
> npm WARN !invalid#1 No repository field.
> npm WARN !invalid#1 No README data
> npm WARN !invalid#1 No license field.
> npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-41-generic
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
> npm ERR! node v4.2.6
> npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
> npm ERR! path /node_modules
> npm ERR! code EACCES
> npm ERR! errno -13
> npm ERR! syscall mkdir
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/node_modules'
> npm ERR!     at Error (native)
> npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/node_modules']
> npm ERR!   errno: -13,
> npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
> npm ERR!   path: '/node_modules' }
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
> npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-41-generic
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
> npm ERR! node v4.2.6
> npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
> npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.3678993639
> npm ERR! code EACCES
> npm ERR! errno -13
> npm ERR! syscall open
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.3678993639'
> npm ERR!     at Error (native)
> npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-
> debug.log.3678993639']
> npm ERR!   errno: -13,
> npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
> npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.3678993639' }
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
> ```

Comment: I fixed the errors and made it working. Thanks !

Comment: Working on another issue after a system crash,

Answer (score 1):

You would need elevated permissions, try `sudo npm install`

Answer (score 1):

Many errors to follow, finally listening to port after all this commands.

> ```
> npm init
> npm install
> npm install -g express
> <Change root>
> root@joseph-APSO:~# npm install npm@latest -g
> root@joseph-APSO:/home/joseph/Downloads/sheets-api-master/start# npm install
> sudo apt-get install nodejs
>
> root@joseph-APSO:/home/joseph/Downloads/sheets-api-master/start# sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
>
> npm install nw-gyp -g
>
> npm rebuild
>
> npm install sqlite3
>
> root@joseph-APSO:/home/joseph/Downloads/sheets-api-master/start# npm start
> ```